# UiView with TableView and CollectionView not refreshing randomly

Tags: swift, tableview, collectionview, reloaddata

I have a UIView that contains a CollectionView and a TableView, both shows data from a service, but sometimes randomly when I enter on this UIView the data is not showing, I am using self.collectionView.reloadData() and self.servicesTableView.reloadData() but it don't shows the information all the times.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0):

A sample of your code would help a lot to figure it out what is happening. But if you do something like this it should work:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) 

    *Do your request*
    After that: 
    self.yourtableview.reloadData()
    self.yourcollectionView.reloadData()


}
```

Comment: I didn't put my code because is very long, but I tried your solution and the problem it's still there. but thanks anyway!